# How to share Ansible deploy user key with team

Tags: ansible

I am working on an Ansible playbook to automate our server provisioning, but I've hit a hard brick wall that I'm not sure how to deal with. On my local system, I generated an SSH keypair to use on my remote hosts. I then manually set up an ansible user on the remote hosts and copied my ansible public key up to them. Now, Ansible can authenticate with my remote hosts without a password. Perfect.

My problem is that this playbook will be stored in a git repo and shared amongst the team. If someone on the team makes a change to the playbook and wants to run it against our remote hosts, they won't be able to because they do not have the private key for the remote 'ansible' user.

What is the proper way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Why do you think there must be only one key?

Comment: I suppose we could just add each developer's public key to the remote ansible users, huh? Then they'd be able to authenticate no problem.

Comment: You could even write a playbook that does that... :)

Comment: I feel like a dummy. Of course you can do that. Do you want to write a quick succinct answer for me so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments the proper way of dealing with this problem is to add the `public ssh key` from each developer to the remote Ansible user. This can be done with Ansible by using the [authorized_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) module like this:

```
- name: Set up authorized keys for ansible user.
  authorized_key:
    user: ansible
    state: present
    key: '{{ item }}'
  with_file:
    - public_keys/doe-jane
    - public_keys/doe-john
```

(I don't like questions not having an accepted answer because the answer is in the comments ...)